# Using an Array as a "goto" label

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, goto

I am working on an Arduino project and was wondering if it is possible to use a value from an array in the `goto` command. Basically, if I have an array of strings where each item corresponds to a label in my code, is there a way to put the array with the appropriate index value in as the label for the command? I am including only a portion of my incomplete code to hopefully help bring my point across.

```c++
int power = 2;
String Labels[4] = {"chip_1", "chip_2", "chip_3", "end"};

chip_1: //label
power += 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {

    buttonState[i] = digitalRead(buttonPins[i]);

    if (buttonState[i] != buttonLastState[i]){
      if (buttonState[i] == HIGH) {
        Serial.println("Button" + String(i) + "ON");
        digitalWrite(buttonPins[i], HIGH);
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("Button" + String(i) + "OFF");
        digitalWrite(buttonPins[i], LOW);
      }

      buttonLastState[i] = buttonState[1];
    }

  }
goto Labels[power]

chip_2: //next label
```

Basically I am having several MCP23017 expander ICs that will each run essentially the same for loop on their respective pins. I want to be able to then have a way to tell the micro controller to activate the for loops of the expander chips in a certain order. My plan was to have an array that had the different labels so that I could change the order of the labels based on which ones were used most recently and thus change the order in which the loops are executed as needed. I haven’t ruled out the possibility that this is unnecessary, but thought it would be interesting to try.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where do you think the control should go to once it hits `goto Labels[power]`?

Comment: Basically I am having several MCP23017 expander ICs that will each run essentially the same for loop on their respective pins. I want to be able to then have a way to tell the micro controller to activate the for loops of the expander chips in a certain order. My plan was to have an array that had the different labels so that I could change the order of the labels based on which ones were used most recently and thus change the order in which the loops are executed as needed. I haven’t ruled out the possibility that this is unnecessary, but thought it would be interesting to try.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a state machine.

Comment: While this almost certainly can be expressed better with C++ means (functors, templates, or a simple switch) it *is* interesting from a language perspective.

Comment: The `switch` statement is not cryptic enough? Or even array of function pointers...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in standard C++, but GCC has [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) extension:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void *arr[3] = {&&label1, &&label2, &&label3};

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        goto *arr[i];
      ret:;
    }

    // Prints `123`

    return 0;

  label1:
    std::cout << 1;
    goto ret;
  label2:
    std::cout << 2;
    goto ret;
  label3:
    std::cout << 3;
    goto ret;
}
```

---

In standard C++ you could store an array of integers instead, and use `switch` to select actions based on those integers.

Alternatively, you could try using an array of function pointers (or even `std::function`s).